# Deploy addin via MDG technology

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've created an addin in EA.
The idea is to distribute it to several teams, each one uses their own repository.
We already distribute an MDG technology.
I was hoping I could integrate the addin in that MDG, but I'm not finding how to do it.
The MDG creation wizard doesn't seem to include addins:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't deploy add-ins using MDG technology.

You'll have to create an installer (.msi) and distribute it that way.